# Customize AttributeError with qualified class name

Tags: python

I have a library where I have defined a class named `FloatTensor` in both modules `torch.tensor` and `torch.sparse`. When I get an attribute error, Python unhelpfully reports that `AttributeError: type object 'FloatTensor' has no attribute 'foo'`, making it unclear whether or not the tensor is sparse. Is there a way to override the reporting behavior so that I get more qualification?

Comment: Is that specific `AttributeError` the only exception you need to modify?

Comment: Well, ideally, I'd like all instances of the class name to be disambiguated when necessary.

Comment: Can you just rename the two `FloatTensor` classes to two different names? I.e `SparseFloatTensor` and `FloatTensor`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing.

Comment: ...never mind, people don't want to change the names ^^

Comment: What about this: override the `__getattr__` of each class, wrap a `super` call in a `try` block and change the message. That was the motivation for my first comment. After seeing your question, I also thought about catching the exception and walking the traceback. I tried some experiments and you could probably make it work in certain cases, but it would be fragile and difficult/impossible to maintain. All that said, your best option is probably to convince people to let you change the names.